# JSONArray and JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой. Подскажите пожайлуста, что не так? И как исправить?

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);


        JSONArray values = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("value");

        Iterator i = values.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            for (int k = 0; k < values.size(); k++){
            JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
            System.out.println("Train number:" + innerObj.get("num"));

            JSONObject value_i = (JSONObject) values.get(k);

            JSONObject from = (JSONObject) value_i.get("from");

            String station_from = (String) from.get("station"); 
            String src_date_from = (String) from.get("src_date"); 
            System.out.println("Station departure: "+station_from);
            System.out.println("Date departure: "+src_date_from);

            JSONObject till = (JSONObject) value_i.get("till"); 
            String station_till = (String) till.get("station"); 
            String src_date_till = (String) till.get("src_date"); 
            System.out.println("Station arrival: " +station_till);
            System.out.println("Date arrival:" +src_date_till);

            JSONArray types =  (JSONArray) values.get(k); 

                for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {
                    JSONObject values2 = (JSONObject) types.get(j);
                    String title = (String)values2.get("title");
                    String letter = (String)values2.get("letter");
                    String places = (String)values2.get("places");
                    System.out.println("Title: "+title);
                    System.out.println("Letter: "+letter);
                    System.out.println("Places:"+places);
                }
            System.out.println("===========================================");
            }



{"value":[{"num":"742\u041b","model":1,"category":1,"from":{"station_id":"2218240","station":"Truskavets","date":1447162980,"src_date":"2015-11-10 15:43:00"},"till":{"station_id":"2200001","station":"Darnytsya","date":1447187400,"src_date":"2015-11-10 22:30:00"},"types":[{"title":"Seating first class","letter":"\u04211","places":151},{"title":"Seating second class","letter":"\u04212","places":346}]},{"num":"050\u041b","model":0,"category":0,"from":{"station_id":"2218240","station":"Truskavets","date":1447179000,"src_date":"2015-11-10 20:10:00"},"till":{"station_id":"2200001","station":"Kyiv-Pasazhyrsky","date":1447218900,"src_date":"2015-11-11 07:15:00"},"types":[{"title":"Suite \/ first-class sleeper","letter":"\u041b","places":1},{"title":"Coupe \/ coach with compartments","letter":"\u041a","places":37},{"title":"Berth \/ third-class sleeper","letter":"\u041f","places":18}]}],"error":false,"data":null}
```

И выдает ошибку на этой строке:

```
JSONArray types =  (JSONArray) values.get(k);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
>       at TestBooking.main(TestBooking.java:48)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `values` - массив объектов:

```
JSONArray values = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("value");
```

Внутри `values` лежат `JSONObject`.

У вас же выше правильно написано:

```
JSONObject value_i = (JSONObject) values.get(k);
```

Уже из этого понятно, что ниже код не выполнится, так как элементы массива - объекты, а не массивы:

```
JSONArray types =  (JSONArray) values.get(k);
```

Судя по логике у вас там должно быть:

```
JSONArray types =  (JSONArray)value_i.get("types");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Заработало:)

Comment: Разброблся...=)